# Updating error in sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

What kind of error is this?

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty
    at Query.formatError (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:159:14)
    at Query._callback (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:35:21)
    at Query.Sequence.end (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:94:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:274:23)
    at Parser.write (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

I'm trying to update an entity with the following code:

```
db.Account.update({
                    'post_id': data.id
                }, {
                  where: { id: account.id }
                })
                .spread(account => {

                  next();
                });
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the column is called `post_id` - maybe its actually `postId` ?

Comment: Having this error as well, did you came up with some solution?

Comment: sounds like something is undefined. either data.id or account.id is undefined and it can't create a query.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The same issue I was facing and after a lot of debugging found out the silly mistake. The reason for me was in mysql added a **column** and forgot to add the same to **sequelize model** representing the same table so for your case also will suggest you to just double check for post_id is present in **Account** sequelize model.

Comment: I had misspelled a column name by not capitalizing a letter correctly (facepalm moment) -- check your casing and spelling!

Comment: Just for reference of others - This "Query was Empty" error occurs in case there is no change in the data. Ref.- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061748/query-was-empty-nodejs-sequlize/48075383